# Prettier formatter Vs code

Tags: html, css

My prettier formatter is not formatting instantly after writing a code

I tried using the settings format on save and used format on save to after modification and it didn't work.

Comment: That save mode is formatting specific things based on source control, it still requires you save the file. I don't believe there is any "Format after every keystroke" setting (And if there was, it would regularly make typing impossible as it attempted to format half-written code/mark-up)

Answer (score 0):

In settings.json make sure that the desired format exists.